# Keeping vertexcoordinates after adding a new vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to add a new vertex to a graph, with fixed VertexCoordinates but when I use VertexAdd, the new graph does not have the VertexCoordinates of the previous one.

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0}}, 
  PlotRange -> 1]
```

This is the initial graph

```
g = VertexAdd[g, 3]
```

Adding a new vertex makes a new graph with automatic coordinates.

I tried to see if there is a way to define the coordinates when adding a new vertex but I could not find anything.

Also I was looking if there is something like:

```
SetProperty[g, VectorCoordinates -> {list of coordinates}]
```

To set coordinates for all vertices in a graph, but I could not find anything.

Comment: related questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31014/how-to-add-new-nodes-to-an-existing-graph-with-fixed-coordinates-nodes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is your `Graph`

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0}},PlotRange -> 1]
```

You can try this!

```
g = SetProperty[VertexAdd[g, {3, 4}],
VertexCoordinates-> PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates]~Join~{{.7, .6}, {-.2, -.3}}];
```

The graph will retain its `VetexCoordinates`

```
EdgeAdd[g, 1 -> 4]
```

[image]