# Deleting Vertices in GridGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Take a simple `GridGraph`:

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 150, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: g]

I am puzzled by the following behavior:

Try to delete vertex 2:

```
h=VertexDelete[g, 2]
```

[image: vd]

Vertex 2 was deleted, but so were several edges that did not have a node at vertex 2. In addition, Vertex 1 appears to be connected to vertex 3; it wasn't before.

Now look at the remaining edges:

```
EdgeList[h]
```

> {1 [UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 [UndirectedEdge] 6, 4 [UndirectedEdge] 5, 
>        4 [UndirectedEdge] 7, 5 [UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 [UndirectedEdge] 8, 
>        6 [UndirectedEdge] 9, 7 [UndirectedEdge] 8, 8 [UndirectedEdge] 9}

According to the edge list, Vertex 1 is not connected to vertex 3 (even though it was draw as connected to 3); but vertex 1 **is** connected to vertex 4 (even though it was not so drawn).

---

Try deleting vertices 1 and 3:

```
VertexDelete[g, {1, 3}]
```

[image: vd2]

Either I am misunderstanding something or Mathematica is erring.
Can anyone explain which is the case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bill's explanation is good. I would also recommend preserving the original grid layout to see things clear:

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 15]
h = SetProperty[VertexDelete[g, #], VertexCoordinates -> Delete[GraphEmbedding[g], #]] &@2
```

[image]

Comment: Useful suggestion. I'm hoping to delete several vertices and then add some extra edges to the grid graph.  Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @David Related thread: [Keeping vertexcoordinates after adding a new vertex](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31235/89)

Comment: Thanks, István.  The thread seems very useful.

Comment: I tested this on a graph, removal of many vertices and structure not preserved so problems: can you preview it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105400/deleting-vertices-from-graph-and-preserving-structure)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can see what is going on by changing the arrangement of the vertices. Here is your g with a circular structure:

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 150, 
    ImagePadding -> 10, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
    PlotLabel -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Now for the h:

```
h = VertexDelete[g, 2]
```

[image]

Now the picture more accurately reflects the structure you expect to see from the `EdgeList`. The problem is basically that the straight lines connecting 1 and 4 happen to pass through 3 in the default arrangement.

Comment: So, I was seeing an optical illusion! Thanks for clearing up the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

More detailed explanation:

`GridGraph` produces a graph with `GraphLayout` property

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 150, ImagePadding -> 10];
PropertyValue[g, GraphLayout]
```

> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {3, 3}}

`VertexDelete` conserved this property

```
h = VertexDelete[g, 2];
PropertyValue[h, GraphLayout]
```

> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {3, 3}}

However, now this embedding is incorrect. You can save vertex positions as in Vitaliy Kaurov's answer. Another method is deleting `GraphLayout` property:

```
SetProperty[h, GraphLayout -> Automatic]
```

[image]