# GridGraph layout with added edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I noticed that the nice symmetric layout of a grid graph gets distorted when additional edges are added to the graph. Is there way to prevent that from happening and to keep the rectangular, grid-like layout?

A minimal example would be

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}]
Graph[Range[9], Join[EdgeList[g], {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}]]
```

giving the following two outputs.

[image]

I would like the additional edge(s) added to the original graph, keeping its layout unchanged.

Thanks.

**Edit**:
I realize that

```
EdgeAdd[g, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5]
```

does what I want. I'd still be interested to learn how I can force a grid-like layout when constructing the graph explicitly from vertex and edge lists, in particular since `EdgeAdd` does not seem to work well with edge weights.

**Edit 2**:
A concrete example of how I would go about constructing the weighted edge would be

```
n=5;
ind = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/2],{n-1,n-1}]+1;
crossedges = Table[{(j-1)n+i \[UndirectedEdge] (j-1)n+i+n+1,(j-1)n+i+1 \[UndirectedEdge] (j-1)n+i+n}[[ind[[j, i]]]],{j,1,n-1},{i,1,n-1}] // Flatten;

g = Graph[Range[n^2],Join[EdgeList[GridGraph[{n,n}]],crossedges],EdgeWeight -> Join[ConstantArray[1,2n(n-1)],ConstantArray[Sqrt[2],(n-1)^2]]];
```

This construction is motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45920/shortest-grid-graph-paths-with-random-diagonal-shortcuts) on MO.

Comment: Please show your use case (how do you want to build the weighted graph)

Comment: duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39835/deleting-vertices-in-gridgraph

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarraher, the linked thread seems very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to take advantage of `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` with `GraphLayout` option.

Take the code in your edit 2 for example.

```
n = 20;
ind = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], {n - 1, n - 1}] + 1;
crossedges = Table[{
                    (j - 1) n + i \[UndirectedEdge] (j - 1) n + i + n + 1,
                    (j - 1) n + i + 1 \[UndirectedEdge] (j - 1) n + i + n
                   }[[ind[[j, i]]]],
                   {j, 1, n - 1}, {i, 1, n - 1}] // Flatten;
```

Save the adjacency matrix for the base `GridGraph` first:

```
gridG = GridGraph[{n, n}];
adjMgg = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[gridG]];
```

Then add the `crossedges` to `gridG`:

```
adjMdg = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[EdgeAdd[gridG, crossedges]]];
```

Construct the weighted adjacency matrix:

```
adjWeight = adjMgg + Sqrt[2] (adjMdg - adjMgg) /. {0 -> ∞};
```

**Use `GraphLayout  -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {n, n}}` to shape the graph:**

```
dg = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[adjWeight,
                            GraphLayout  -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {n, n}},
                            EdgeStyle    -> Directive[GrayLevel[.7]],
                            VertexStyle  -> GrayLevel[.9], VertexSize -> 0.05,
                            ImagePadding -> 10]
```

Now we are ready for computing the shortest path:

```
Module[{i = 1, j = n^2, path},
       path = FindShortestPath[dg, i, j];
       HighlightGraph[dg,
                      PathGraph @ path,
                      GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
      ]
```

[image: shortest path on grid graph]