# Clickable graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, dynamic, gui-construction

Can someone help me to make a clickable graph?

```
  Graph[{1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2}]
```

I found that `VertexDelete` removes desirable vertex and edges, but I don't know how to make it clickable and delete that vertex (and his edges) which was clicked by user.

I already have:

```
DynamicModule[
    { selection = {}
    , gr = {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2}
    }
  , Dynamic[
        Graph[gr
          , PlotLabel -> selection
          , VertexShapeFunction -> ( EventHandler[Disk[#1, .1]
              , "MouseClicked" :> (selection = #2; VertexDelete[gr, selection];
            )] &)
        ]
    ]
]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: So, you only expect to remove vertices, as opposed to adding them?

Comment: Once there was `GraphEdit` I don't know if it still works in later versions: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphUtilities/ref/GraphEdit.html

Comment: yes, exactly @J.M.

Comment: @mattiav27 Powerful undocumental function!I'm looking forward to you make it as an answer. :)

Comment: This is old but maybe can help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31014/5478

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are almost there but `VertexDelete[graph, n]` or e.g. `SetProperty[graph, spec]` won't affect `graph` they way you are expecting unless you set it again: `graph = VertexDelete[graph, n]`.

```
DynamicModule[{graph}
  , Dynamic[graph]
  , Initialization :> (
        graph = Graph[ 
            {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2}
          , VertexLabels -> "Name"
          , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
          , VertexShapeFunction -> ( EventHandler[   Disk[#1, .1]
              , "MouseClicked" :> (graph = VertexDelete[graph, #2];)
            ] & )
        ]
    )     
]
```

And if you want to keep original `VertexCoordinates` you need to set them explicitly first:

```
 DynamicModule[{graph}
  , Dynamic[graph]
  , Initialization :> (
        graph = Graph[ 
            {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 2}
          , VertexLabels -> "Name"
          , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
          , VertexShapeFunction -> ( EventHandler[   Disk[#1, .1]
              , "MouseClicked" :> (graph = VertexDelete[graph, #2];)
              , Method -> "Queued" (*should help for bigger graphs*)
            ] & )
        ]
      ; graph = SetProperty[graph, 
             VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[graph]
        ]
    )     
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great work! Out of curiousity, how did you make this *.gif? Any reference to where I could learn more about it?

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Thanks :) I'm using SceenToGif, quite handy.

Comment: brilliant! Thank you very much!

Comment: "but `Graphs` are not mutable" In fact `Graph`s *are*, weirdly, mutable, to such an extent that some undocumented functions do this:  `a=Graph[...]; b=a; undocumentedGraphFunction[b]` — and now `a` is changed as well!  I know that I am being nitpicky about a small comment, but this behaviour (not your comment) has really bothered me.

Comment: Here is a practical consequence of this mutability: the procedural solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143607/12) is much faster than the functional one.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for those points, I'm not so much familiar with all  those problems. I should probably say something like 'mutable in a sense of SetProperties or setting parts of specific values'. But since I don't know that I will just phrase it more safely :)

Comment: There is also a `Button` property for each vertex, which can set an action to run on click.  There is an example under Scope -> Wrappers.  I tried to make a better solution than yours with it, but I do not think it is possible.  The necessity for strict evaluation control makes this approach less clear (and longer) than yours.

Comment: @Szabolcs I certainly knew about `Button` wrapper but I don't remember why I went with `EventHandler`. Probably from the same reason as you.

Comment: I made a small edit to prevent the arrowheads from getting clipped. I learned this from @halmir recently. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Szabolcs sure I don't mind, thanks. p.s. EventHandler now supports `"Queued"` Method so it may be a good idea for bigger graphs. Don't have much experience with Graphs performance.